# How to calculate this trigonometric sum

Tags: trigonometry, direct-sum

In this exercise i have to calculate this sum :

> $$S=1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos^2(x)}+\ldots+\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos^n(x)}$$

There is no hint in the exercise.
I tried to use trigonometric identities but i didn't find the solution

Comment: Have you tried using complex numbers?

Comment: How i çan use them to solve this ?

Comment: Consider the similar series but with $\sin$'s on the numerator.

Comment: Can you explain more, i'm unable to solve it

Comment: No probelm, take your time

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you! Do you have any questions?

Comment: Final result should be $$\frac{\sin (n+1) x}{\sin x \cos ^n x}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let
$$C = 1 + \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos^2(x)} + \cdots + \frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos^n(x)}$$
$$S = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(x)} + \cdots + \frac{\sin(nx)}{\cos^n(x)}$$
So
$$\begin{align}C+iS&=1+\frac{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}+\frac{\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(x)}+...+\frac{\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)}{\cos^n(x)}
\\&=1+\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}+\frac{e^{2ix}}{\cos^2(x)}+\cdots+\frac{e^{nix}}{\cos^n(x)}\\
&=1+\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)+\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)-1}\\
&=\frac{e^{(n+1)ix}-\cos^{n+1}(x)}{\cos^{n+1}(x)}\times\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{ix}-\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos^n(x)}\left(\frac{e^{(n+1)ix}-\cos^{n+1}(x)}{e^{ix}-\cos(x)}\right)\end{align}$$
Now try simplifying this and equating real and imaginary parts. If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I have a question:

$$=\frac{\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)-1}\\$$

I thought this line should be:

$$=\frac{1-\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{\cos(x)}\right)}\\$$

Because the formula for the sum of geometric series is $\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

Why?:

$$=\frac{e^{(n+1)ix}-\cos^{n+1}(x)}{\cos^{n+1}(x)}\times\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{ix}-\cos(x)}$$

I multiply the numerator and denominator for $[\cos(x)]^{n+1}$

$$\dfrac{\cos^{n+1}(x)-e^{ix}\cos^{n+1}(x)}{\cos^{n+1}(x)-e^{ix}\cos^{n}(x)}$$

Comment: Also the sum of Raffaele is different, how come?

$$\dfrac{\sin(n+1)x}{\sin(x)\cos^{n}(x)}$$

Comment: I wish to ask you what does it mean to equate the real and imaginary part?

Comment: @JamesWarthington for your first question: the $2$ formulae are identical; it is like the equality $$\frac{-a}{-b}=\frac{a}{b}$$. For your second point, you made a small error; multiplying the top and bottom by $\cos^{n+1}(x)$ actually yields $$\frac{\cos^{n+1}(x)-e^{(n+1)ix}}{\cos^{n+1}(x)-e^{ix}\cos^{n}(x)}$$ For your third question, Raffaele's result is actually the same as mine, it's just that I left the final parts of rearrangement etc to the OP. I can show you how that works if you want. For your fourth question: (continued below)

Comment: @JamesWarthington (continued) if I have an equation $$p+iq=a+ib$$ where $p,q,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then we can deduce that $p=a$ and $q=b$, as real numbers don't change the imaginary component of a complex number, and vice versa. This is called equating real and imaginary parts, as we are equating the real part of each side and also equating the imaginary part of each side.